# FS Development - KMDF Windows Driver

Tags: windows, filesystems, driver, kmdf, irp

I am new here and am trying to develop a concept fs driver for the tar 'filesystem' (mount tar). My question is, how does the OS detect that a partition has the TAR filesystem and automatically load my driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all loaded FS called [IoRegisterFileSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548494(v=vs.85).aspx) - this routine inserts the device object into the list of file systems in the system. then you must have a WRK. when say file opened on device with [VPB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff625892(v=vs.85).aspx) `IopCheckVpbMounted` is called and he call `IopMountVolume` - this is key point for mount understand. this routine first walk through list with registered FS and send [IRP_MN_MOUNT_VOLUME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548670(v=vs.85).aspx) to all until some FS not return success code. also the last entry in the list - special File system recognizer - he try determinate format of the volume. and if yes - he return `STATUS_FS_DRIVER_REQUIRED` - indicates that need load new FS for this volume. system in this case call `IopLoadFileSystemDriver`. this routine is invoked when a mini-file system recognizer driver recognizes a volume as being a particular file system, but the driver for that file system has not yet been loaded. at the current moment FS_Rec.sys support next FS:

```
cdfs
ReFS
ReFSv1 // begin from win 10
ExFat
FastFat
Udfs
Ntfs
```

for support other - you need or auto load self FS driver or self recognizer (mini driver) which recognize your FS and return `STATUS_FS_DRIVER_REQUIRED` on `IRP_MJ_FILE_SYSTEM_CONTROL.IRP_MN_MOUNT_VOLUME` and load your FS (by ZwLoadDriver call ) on `IRP_MJ_FILE_SYSTEM_CONTROL.IRP_MN_LOAD_FILE_SYSTEM`